# Can I execute batch of queries using jpa/hibernate in a single shot?

Tags: java, jpa

Here is a sample code.
sourceFileItemNo and entityDplStatus are array of some values.

```
Query query; 
for(int i = 0 ;(sourceFileItemNo!=null && i< sourceFileItemNo.length); i++){
    Object[] parameters = {entityDplStatus[i],"1",sourceFileItemNo[i]};
    String queryString = "UPDATE GtcEntityDetailsValue c SET c.dplStatus=?1 where c.referenceNo=?2 and c.itemNo=?3";
    query = manager.createQuery(queryString);
    query = setQueryParameters(query, parameters);
    query.executeUpdate();
}
```

Here in this case we are updating the details each time in each iteration. Does JPA provides provision to add the queries to a list or something and execute all the queries in a single shot just like old connection statement execute batch?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can easily do it using hibernate,pass the list of objects with updated values that you want to persist, then  just do:

```
 private void updteRecord(List<Records> records){
    int batchSize=10;
    for(int i=0;i<records.size();i++)
    {
        getSession().saveOrUpdate(records.get(i));

        if(i%batchSize==0)
        {
            getSession().flush();
            getSession().clear();
        }
    }
}
```

The List of records you are feeding to this method should contain the values you need to upodate.

Comment: Here we are passing collection/list of entities for batch update right? This will work. But my question is, can we execute as list of queries itself in a single shot using jpa?